# How do I compare individual elements in a string?

Tags: c

I am practicing on Hackerank and I am stuck on the first problem.  I am supposed to be writing a code that matches pairs of socks. "For example, there are n=7 socks with colors ar = [1,2,1,2,3,2]. There is one pair of color 1 and one pair of color 2. There are three odd socks left, one of each color. The number of pairs is 2."

The constraints of the problem are 1 ≤ n ≤ 100 and 1 ≤ ar[i] ≤ 100 where 0 ≤ i < n.

My idea to count how many times each color occurs then divide that number by 2 then add all the pairs together. I don't know how to write the loop to compare 100 possible colors and have separate counters for each. I have included what I've got so far but it isn't good.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(ar[i] == ar[i+1])
    {
         sum1 = sum1 + 1;
    }
}

if(sum1 % 2 == 1)
{
    sum1 = sum1 - 1;
}

sum1 = sum1 / 2;
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: The colors are numbers from 1 to 100. Can you think of a way to store 100 different counts in C?

Comment: If you had a bag of colored socks, how would you count the pairs?

Answer (score 1):

"I don't know how to write the loop to compare 100 possible colors and have separate counters for each."

You can have separate counters for each by defining an array for the counters.  Conveniently for you, the "colors" are integers, so your array index can serve as the "color" you are counting.  The value stored (at each element in the array) would be the number of times you've seen that "color" in the input.

Then, loop over the input, and increment the corresponding element in your array of counters.  In this way, it doesn't matter if a given sock's match is next in line in the input or several input elements away, and you won't need to do anything expensive like comparing every input element to every other input element.

At the end of that looping, loop over your array of counters; the value in each element will tell you about that "color" sock:

```
0           : no socks of that color in the input
odd number  : there are `x / 2` pairs of this color and an odd sock
even number : there are `x / 2` pairs of this color
```

Count the number of pairs and odd socks as you go, and at the end you have your total number of pairs of socks and of odd socks, which I presume is the output you want.

Comment: Wouldn't I still have 100 if statements then? One for each "color"?

Comment: no; see the example code in @Jdog 's answer; the second loop shows how to test each element in the array of counters

Comment: @mulletjson  : overall, the answer from Jdog is a fine expression in code of what I've said in words -- and Jdog beat me to it by 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array that just stores a counter for each possibility.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    newAr[ar[i]]++;
}
```

Then % through each of those elements. The resulting array for your array ar = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2] would be newAr = [0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0].

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    numPairs += newAr[i]/2;
    if(newAr[i] % 2 == 1){
        numOddSocks++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an array of 100 items. One for each color.